# How to get the square of a number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

I am trying to get the square of a number between **0** and **9**, and then I will use that **number** to create the **height** of the **rectangle**.

What I've tried is using the sum method `Ex: 5*5 = 25` and `5+5+5+5+5 = 25`

```
;Keyboard Input
mov ah, 3Fh
mov bx, 0
mov cx, 1
mov dx, num
int 21h

;Multiplication
sub [num], 48
mov al,[num]
mov bl,[num]
mult:
 add al, [num]
 dec bl
 jnz mult
```

I am wondering if this correct because when I insert the number **7** (7*7) = **49** I think it exceeds the value of **50** (**length** of the **rectangle**);

[image]

And when the number **0** is inserted this strange **behaviour** happens:

[image]

Code to create the rectangle:

```
mov [height], al
mov cx, [pos_x]
mov dx, [pos_y]

loop_y:

 loop_x:
  mov ah, 0ch
  mov al, [cor]
  mov bh, 0
  int 10h
  inc cx
  dec [length]
  jnz loop_x

 inc [pos_y]
 mov dx, [pos_y]
 mov cx, [pos_x]
 mov [length], 50
 dec [height]
 jnz loop_y
```

Everything needs to be **FASM** compatible.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the x87 floating point unit?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want the *square root* and not the *square?*  To square a number (i.e. multiply it with itself), use a `mul` or `imul` instruction.  Refer to the instruction set reference for details.

Comment: I want the square yes, not the square root.

Comment: Then read about the `mul` and `imul` instructions.

Comment: I was able to do this with mul thank you.

Comment: Raising an integer to a power can be done by (repetitive) multiplication, just as multiplication can be accomplished by (repetitive) addition.

Comment: Why is the result of the multiplication stored in ax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   mov al,[num]
>   mov bl,[num]
> mult:
>   add al, [num]
>   dec bl
>   jnz mult
> ```
>
> I am wondering if this correct because when I insert the number 7 (7*7) = 49 I think it exceeds the value of 50 (length of the rectangle);

If you write this multiplication following your addition scheme 7+7+7+7+7+7+7, you will notice that there's **6** additions. Your program performs **7** additions and thus you obtain 56 as your final result!

You have 2 options.

- Either you do 1 addition less

  ```
    mov al, [num]
    mov bl, [num]
    dec bl
  mult:
    add al, [num]
    dec bl
    jnz mult
  ```
- or you start the result (`AL`) at 0.

  ```
    mov al, 0
    mov bl, [num]
  mult:
    add al, [num]
    dec bl
    jnz mult
  ```

> And when the number 0 is inserted this strange behaviour happens:

Because the decrement `dec bl` will wraparound from 0 to 255, this time your program will perform 256 additions of 0, yielding a 0 result.
Later your drawing routine will use this 0 without checking and also loop 256 times.

---

The instruction set has a multiplication instruction. Your code becomes:

```
mov al, [num]
mul al           ; -> AX = AL * AL
```

> Why is the result of the multiplication stored in ax?

To accomodate the largest possible outcome from a multiplication.
Consider calculating 255 * 255 whose product is 65025. You need a 16-bit container to store this whole. And it is the `AX` register because the designer of the CPU chose to use the accumulator exclusively for multiplications via `mul`. In later generations of the x86 architecture, the `imul` instruction was enhanced so it could use any of the general purpose registers to hold the result.